# VB.Net How Does the Designer Handle Dynamically Created Objects at Runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am making a custom control, and it has a property for the NumberOfDatabases available in the control. The default is for there to be one ComboBox called PrimaryDatabase, and if NumberOfDatabases is set from 1 to 2, then another combobox is created and put underneath the existing ComboBox. It seems like the code to create this ComboBox is ran in the designer, and then ran again at runtime. When dealing with dynamically created objects like this, do the objects have to be created in the designer and at runtime again? And how does the designer handle dynamically creating objects when I switch my NumberOfDatabases property? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the form designer code you'll see that it is very much the same as code you would write to add a control at runtime.  VS does run the designer code in order to present you with the rendered form...(which would include your UserControl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just appear and behave like they do at runtime.  The designer is otherwise completely oblivious to them since it wasn't asked to create them.  So you cannot select them nor set their properties.  And they won't be serialized into the usercontrol's InitializeComponent() method.  Can't operate them with the mouse or keyboard either, the designer intercepts that.  So you merely see them.  WYSIWYG was a strong goal in the Winforms designer.

The odds that this is *actually* correct tend to be iffy.  There often is some kind of dbase code that runs at well, the odds that it functions correctly are never good because you don't have the proper configuration.  Exceptions at design-time are pretty nasty and can destroy designs, making stuff disappear without the programmer noticing.  YMMV.

Use the [DesignMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your code to prevent risky code from running at design time.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem that I am actually having is for a UseDefaultPath property for each database. If the UseDefaultPath property is set to false, I want to dynamically create a textbox that the user can enter in a path for the MDF/NDF to be created at. The code dictates that the textbox will be created under the PrimaryDatabase, and the label\combobox for the dynamically created secondary database be shifted down beneath the newly added textbox. Everything works fine if I add the textbox before adding the second combobox under it, but if I create the second combobox, then a

Comment: then add the textbox, and then shift the second combobox underneath it, I am getting weird results in the designer (although it functions correctly at runtime)

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I warned you about, isn't it?  Use the DesignMode property.

Comment: Yes it is, so if I am trying to set the location properties for a dynamically created control there will be issues. I know I can use If Me.DesignMode, is this what you are referring to?